# Can i access other user onedrvie folders using power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, onedrive-for-business, onedrive

A user inside our organization has shared 3 folders with me inside his one drive , as follow:-

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1706388518769.png]

now can i access all the root folders inside the other user onedrvie and then get the latest file inside each root folder? so the question is can i access other user onedrive root folders that have been shared with me using power automate?

Thanks

Hint. currently i can access the other user onedrive folders using the browser (as shown in the  above picture), but i do not have my own onedrive, and my account will show this message when i try to access my own one drvie:-

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1706388757006.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access other user's OneDrive by using power automate, please use other user's OneDrive account in the connection.

[image]